# "and" functions in ocaml

Tags: function, ocaml

I'm working on an ocaml project and I'm learning the syntax.  I saw a program with the following format:

```
 let foo1 = function
    |(x, y) -> foo2 (x,y) z
 and foo2 a s=
    (*stuff in here*)
```

I'm concerned with what the `and` is doing in there.  I tried looking online for what that could mean, but I can't seem to find anything.  It could also just be a typo...any advice would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`and` is used to define mutually recursive functions/data types.

Without `and`, you can't call both `foo2` from `foo1` and `foo1` from `foo2`, you can only have one of these.

You also need `rec` in your example to make it work. Without `rec`, `and` is just like a normal `let`.

Here's two mutually recursive function definitions:

```
let rec some_fun1 _ =
    print_endline "fun1";
    some_fun2 ()

and some_fun2 _ =
    print_endline "fun2";
    some_fun1 ()
```

(like I've said above, without `rec` this can't work)

Comment: Without `rec`, it's like a `let`, but with the constraint that even the second definition cannot reference the first.

Comment: "Without rec, and is just like a normal let" Not necessarily. The expression in the `let` is evaluated in the scope outside the `let`. So if you have nested `let`s, the second `let`'s expression is evaluated in the scope of the first `let`; whereas if you use `and`, both of them would evaluate in the outer scope. For example, `let x = 2 in let y = 3 in let x = y and y = x in y` evaluates to 2, but `let x = 2 in let y = 3 in let x = y in let y = x in y` evaluates to 3